# CSS not working on ie11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I know we're not meant to post images but I do not know how to explain this.

I've some CSS to colour a button red.  It works on Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Opera etc.  In fact it works on everything except ie11 which the client uses.  The thing is, when I use DOM Explorer it tells me the button is given the right background-color.  In the image you can see the Delete button has been selected and it shows the background color as #bd362f but you can see from looking above the button isn't.

What's going on?[image]

Comment: I was wondering, for buttons accept/reject, whey you applying css btn-primary and then btn-success together? We cant see the css properly, it is to do with overiding css background-color.

Comment: There is another background there, as you point out, but it is simple applying a color gradient to the button between 2 reds.  No reason for it to not work on ie11 when it works on everything else

Comment: I do hate it when people down vote something without leaving a comment.  If the solution is so obvious, write it and downgrade the question

Answer (score -1):

There's another background in front of your color.
Look closely in the bottom-right corner of the screenshot, a '`background`' statement is there and is not overrided.

You could simply change your `background-color` to `background`, this should do the trick.